Prevent MongoDB's bulkWrite from returning (too much) data
I use MongoDB with the Node.js driver to bulkWrite around 10,000 rather large documents (1-5 MB per document) from an AWS scheduled task to MongoDB instance every hour.
I would expect the inbound network usage in the MongoDB instance to increase every time it runs (obviously), however, what I do not understand is why the outbound traffic is growing equally so (precisely at the time of the bulk write, every hour).
I assume it is returning the updated/inserted documents behind the scenes (and not just the inserted ID's).
Is there any way to prevent it, preferably including the inserted ID's as well? I am not using this returned data in any way, so it is a lot of unnecessary data transfers that I'm being charged for, so I would like to disable it.

Are you using AWS documentDB instead of MongoDB? If so, you might find IO-optimized useful.

No, I am using MongoDB. DocumentDB is not an option in my usecase.

Outbound to where? If this is a replica set then all of those writes need to be propagated to the SECONDARY nodes as well
